Impossible to draw pixel-perfect aliased 2D lines?
Would like to draw pixel-perfect aliased 2D lines in Unity but I can't get a good result.
Code:
using UnityEngine;

public class GLTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    [HideInInspector]
    private Material Material;

    public Vector3Int Point1 = new(0, 0, 0);

    public Vector3Int Point2 = new(50, 10, 0);

    private readonly Vector3 Half = Vector3.one * 0.5f;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (Material == null)
        {
            Material = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored"))
            {
                hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave
            };
        }
    }

    private void OnRenderObject()
    {
        Material.SetPass(0);

        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadPixelMatrix();
        GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
        GL.Color(Color.red);
        GL.Vertex(Point1 + Half);
        GL.Vertex(Point2 + Half);
        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
    }
}

Result:
With camera MSAA off, lots overlapping present:

With camera MSAA on, almost how it should but with extra AA pixels:

How it's expected to be, drawn by hand in Paint.NET:

Question:
How can I get aliased 2D lines to draw correctly in Unity?
